# How to remove the fragment when click on item again

Tags: android, fragment

Good Day,

I am facing some problem with fragments

I am displaying a fragment when user clicks on 'More', as a popup menu

[image]

but when I click the 'More' again, it would be like add one more fragment on the previous one

can someone tell me how to remove the fragment when I click on the 'More' again? Thank you!

[image]

the java code of bottom navigation menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            String title = "";
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MenuFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    title = "MENU";
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                    break;
                case R.id.promotion:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PromotionFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    title = "PROMOTION";
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                    break;
                case R.id.order:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OrderFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    title = "ORDER";
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                    break;
                case R.id.location:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new LocationFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    title = "LOCATION";
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                    break;
                case R.id.more:
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new MoreFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }});

}

}
```

Comment: Add your code and XML file.

Comment: It would help a lot if you added some code…

Comment: add your code how you add this fragment on more button click

Comment: I'll advice don't use a Fragment use a Dialog instead for such bottom popup menus.

Comment: Show the fragment transaction code.. You can remove it by fragment manager.popBackStack();

Comment: i updated the code already, thanks for help me and i just start learning android so now i will have many question ><

Answer (score 0):

Do not add your Popup `Fragment` to the `backstack` while transitioning to a new one. That is the first step you should do.

Next, rather than reopening the Popup on second "more" click, you should close it. Sounds like a better approach. But this would be probably better achieved by using [Dialogs.](https://material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to keep track of fragment state. Lets assume a variable `isFragmentOpen`. In onClick you have to flip the variable and take your decision.

```
private boolean isFragmentOpen;

void onClick(View view) {

    if (!isFragmentOpen) {
        addFragment();
    } else {
        removeFragment();
    }
    // Flip the fragment state.
    isFragmentOpen = !isFragmentOpen;

}
```

Please check how to add or delete fragment from official document [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

before calling transaction for 'more' add a tag with addToBackStack function(ex: moreFragment). check fragment manager and remove fragment like:

```
 Fragment mFragment =getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("moreFragment");
 if(mFragment != null)
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragment);
```

But I think instead of removing old fragment just keep it and dont open new one if not null

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping and now i already solve the problem^^

this is the code what i using

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    MoreFragment f = (MoreFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("tag");

                    if(f == null) {  // not added
                        f = new MoreFragment();
                        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, f, "tag");
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

                    } else {  // already added

                        ft.remove(f);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
                    }
                    ft.commit();
                    break;
```